# How to filter out a list of names in a column based on a condition in Amazon Quicksight?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

Suppose I have a table of two Columns

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | France |
| A | USA |
| B | Germany |
| B | Spain |
| C | Netherland |
| C | USA |
| D | Japan |
| E | USA |
| F | Canada |

How could I remove (in **Quicksight**) all the elements in Col1 if it contains **USA** at least once in Col2  ?

Final Table should look like this:-

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| B | Germany |
| B | Spain |
| D | Japan |
| F | Canada |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [calculated field](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/adding-a-calculated-field-analysis.html). Using [countIf](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/countIf-function.html) and [sumOver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/sumOver-function.html), an example would be like this:

```
sumOver
(
  countIf({Col2}, {Col2} = 'USA'),
  [{Col1}]
)
```

Then use a filter in your analysis, such as *<your_calculated_field_name>* Equals 0

Comment: Will sumOver work for a dimension field?

Comment: No. sumOver only works on measure fields. countOver can work on both but then you will be taking out the logic to compare Col2 with USA

Comment: Thank you @occamatic. Your solution worked. Could you please explain the logic as it is a little difficult to understand the solution?

Comment: So break it down into 2 parts, the countIf({Col2}, {Col2} = 'USA') part creates a new 'column' for every row that becomes a 1 if Col2 is USA and a 0 if not, the sumOver part then let's you 'group' by the value of another column, in this case where Col1 is the same as itself, so all the 1s are added together where Col1 is the same, hope this makes sense

Comment: Thank You for the explanation! It is clear now.

Comment: Hello @occamatic!! The filter solution you provided works with Table visuals only as the filter is a table calculation but it doesn't work with any other visuals for eg, pie chart or line chart. Is there any way to create a similar filter which will work with all the visuals??

Comment: Unfortunately because the calculated field relies on Col1 it must be used in the visual somewhere. I know this is annoying if you want any of these other visuals used for Col2 but it is just the way it works. The only alternative would be to filter out the rows that have USA in Col2 before the data gets to QuickSight, but I am not sure if this is an option for you.

Comment: Yes, it is annoying a bit. USA  was an eg, I have to filter many things similar To USA where I have to filter out Col1 which have 2 specific values in col2 and it is a bit tricky on Quicksight. But Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Hello @occamatic! I am working on something and a bit lost. Could you please help me with it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70961411/how-can-i-add-new-columns-to-the-original-dataset-each-month-using-aws-databrew