# How can I add new columns to the original dataset each month using AWS Databrew or other AWS services

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-databrew

Suppose I have a table with 3 Columns for the month of January

| Name | Start Date | Items Purchased |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01/01 | 2 |
| B | 01/01 | 4 |
| C | 01/01 | 5 |
| D | 01/01 | 7 |
| E | 01/01 | 1 |

I will receive two similar datasets for the month of Feb and March

**FEB**

| Name | Start Date | Items Purchased |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01/01 | 1 |
| C | 01/01 | 4 |
| D | 01/01 | 2 |
| G | 01/02 | 1 |
| H | 01/02 | 6 |

**MARCH**

| Name | Start Date | Items Purchased |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 01/01 | 6 |
| C | 01/01 | 4 |
| G | 01/02 | 2 |
| H | 01/02 | 3 |
| J | 01/03 | 1 |

Now, I will receive similar datasets for subsequent months and hence I want to automate the whole process. In my final Dataset I want to keep one column each for **Name** and **Start Date**. But I want three different columns of **Items Purchased** for each month.

| Name | Start Date | Items Purchased Jan | Items Purchased Feb | Items Purchased Mar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01/01 | 2 | 1 | NA |
| B | 01/01 | 4 | NA | 6 |
| C | 01/01 | 5 | 4 | 4 |
| D | 01/01 | 7 | 2 | NA |
| E | 01/01 | 1 | NA | NA |
| G | 01/02 | NA | 1 | 2 |
| H | 01/02 | NA | 6 | 3 |
| J | 01/03 | NA | NA | 1 |

Is it possible to achieve the result(with automation) as shown in the above table using AWS Databrew or any other AWS services?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have got a solution already.
Within AWS DataBrew, you can schive this in two steps. Once new columns are created, you can populate the data as required based on your logic.

```
{
    "RecipeAction": {
        "Operation": "DUPLICATE",
        "Parameters": {
            "sourceColumn": "Items Purchased",
            "targetColumn": "Items Purchased Jan"
        }
    }
},
{
    "RecipeAction": {
        "Operation": "DUPLICATE",
        "Parameters": {
            "sourceColumn": "Items Purchased",
            "targetColumn": "Items Purchased Feb"
        }
    }
},
{
    "RecipeAction": {
        "Operation": "DUPLICATE",
        "Parameters": {
            "sourceColumn": "Items Purchased",
            "targetColumn": "Items Purchased Mar"
        }
    }
},
{
    "RecipeAction": {
        "Operation": "DELETE",
        "Parameters": {
            "sourceColumn": "Items Purchased"
        }
    }
}
```